# How to implement rollback using Wixsharp (Wix#) installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I'm new in MSI installers, wix and wixsharp. I need to implement installer with some actions during the installation process (like call some *.exe or set up task scheduler and so on). Bu in case of any problems and exceptions I need a rollback all installed items.

1. How to implement a rollback using Wixsharp (Wix#) ? I found no information on the page of this porject.
2. I can't figure out the practical difference between custom action and before\after install event handler. What for do I need to use exactly custom action, instead of isuage of AfterInstall even handler in wix# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of wix# helped me with rollback using permissions elevations and third party referencies to assemblies (most difficult case).

Full answer is here: https://wixsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/646337

in common way rollback can be done like this:

```
project.AfterInstall += project_AfterInstall;
...
static void project_AfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        e.Session.Log(ex.Message);
        e.Result = ActionResult.Failure;
    }
}
```

Comment: the link is wrong.